# I keep getting errors for UE4 FPS Section 3.1 tutorial. What should I do?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, unreal-engine4

For the following codes I'm supposed to add a projectile and be able to fire it yet the lines of code provided by UE4 to do so don't compile. Whenever I compile, it gives me multiple error codes. Below are the codes used for this project.

FPSProjectile.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "FPSProjectile.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class FPSPROJECT_API AFPSProjectile : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AFPSProjectile();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    // Sphere collision component.
    UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, Category = Projectile)
    USphereComponent* CollisionComponent;

    // Projectile movement component.
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = Movement)
    UProjectileMovementComponent* ProjectileMovementComponent;

    // Function that initializes the projectile's velocity in the shoot direction.
    void FireInDirection(const FVector& ShootDirection);
};
```

FPSCharacter.cpp

```
#include "FPSProject.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.h"

// Sets default values
AFPSCharacter::AFPSCharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Create a first person camera component.
    FPSCameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));
    // Attach the camera component to our capsule component.
    FPSCameraComponent->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent());
    // Position the camera slightly above the eyes.
    FPSCameraComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f + BaseEyeHeight));
    // Allow the pawn to control camera rotation.
    FPSCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;

    // Create a first person mesh component for the owning player.
    FPSMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonMesh"));
    // Only the owning player sees this mesh.
    FPSMesh->SetOnlyOwnerSee(true);
    // Attach the FPS mesh to the FPS camera.
    FPSMesh->SetupAttachment(FPSCameraComponent);
    // Disable some environmental shadowing to preserve the illusion of having a single mesh.
    FPSMesh->bCastDynamicShadow = false;
    FPSMesh->CastShadow = false;

    // The owning player doesn't see the regular (third-person) body mesh.
    GetMesh()->SetOwnerNoSee(true);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AFPSCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (GEngine)
    {
        // Put up a debug message for five seconds. The -1 "Key" value (first argument) indicates that we will never need to update or refresh this message.
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("We are using FPSCharacter."));
    }
}

// Called every frame
void AFPSCharacter::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AFPSCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Set up "movement" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &AFPSCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &AFPSCharacter::MoveRight);

    // Set up "look" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &AFPSCharacter::AddControllerYawInput);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &AFPSCharacter::AddControllerPitchInput);

    // Set up "action" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &AFPSCharacter::StartJump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Released, this, &AFPSCharacter::StopJump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, &AFPSCharacter::Fire);
}

void AFPSCharacter::MoveForward(float Value)
{
    // Find out which way is "forward" and record that the player wants to move that way.
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::X);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void AFPSCharacter::MoveRight(float Value)
{
    // Find out which way is "right" and record that the player wants to move that way.
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::Y);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void AFPSCharacter::StartJump()
{
    bPressedJump = true;
}

void AFPSCharacter::StopJump()
{
    bPressedJump = false;
}

void AFPSCharacter::Fire()
{
}
```

FPSCharacter.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class FPSPROJECT_API AFPSCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AFPSCharacter();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    // Handles input for moving forward and backward.
    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveForward(float Value);

    // Handles input for moving right and left.
    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveRight(float Value);

    // Sets jump flag when key is pressed.
    UFUNCTION()
    void StartJump();

    // Clears jump flag when key is released.
    UFUNCTION()
    void StopJump();

    // Function that handles firing projectiles.
    UFUNCTION()
    void Fire();

    // FPS camera.
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    class UCameraComponent* FPSCameraComponent;

    // First-person mesh (arms), visible only to the owning player.
    UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, Category = Mesh)
    USkeletalMeshComponent* FPSMesh;

    // Gun muzzle's offset from the camera location.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Gameplay)
    FVector MuzzleOffset;

    // Projectile class to spawn.
    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = Projectile)
    TSubclassOf<class AFPSProjectile> ProjectileClass;
};
```

FPSProjectile.cpp

```
#include "FPSProject.h"
#include "FPSProjectile.h"

// Sets default values
AFPSProjectile::AFPSProjectile()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Use a sphere as a simple collision representation.
    CollisionComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("SphereComponent"));
    // Set the sphere's collision radius.
    CollisionComponent->InitSphereRadius(15.0f);
    // Set the root component to be the collision component.
    RootComponent = CollisionComponent;

    // Use this component to drive this projectile's movement.
    ProjectileMovementComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UProjectileMovementComponent>(TEXT("ProjectileMovementComponent"));
    ProjectileMovementComponent->SetUpdatedComponent(CollisionComponent);
    ProjectileMovementComponent->InitialSpeed = 3000.0f;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->MaxSpeed = 3000.0f;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->bRotationFollowsVelocity = true;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->bShouldBounce = true;
    ProjectileMovementComponent->Bounciness = 0.3f;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AFPSProjectile::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AFPSProjectile::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

}

// Function that initializes the projectile's velocity in the shoot direction.
void AFPSProjectile::FireInDirection(const FVector& ShootDirection)
{
    ProjectileMovementComponent->Velocity = ShootDirection * ProjectileMovementComponent->InitialSpeed;
}
```

The following is the errors I get

error "FPSCharacter.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in FPSCharacter.h"
^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.cpp:16:23: error: member access into incomplete type 'class UCameraComponent' FPSCameraComponent->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent()); ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.h:50:11: note: forward declaration of 'UCameraComponent' class UCameraComponent* FPSCameraComponent; ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.cpp:18:23: error: member access into incomplete type 'class UCameraComponent' FPSCameraComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f + BaseEyeHeight)); ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.h:50:11: note: forward declaration of 'UCameraComponent' class UCameraComponent* FPSCameraComponent; ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.cpp:20:23: error: member access into incomplete type 'class UCameraComponent' FPSCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true; ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.h:50:11: note: forward declaration of 'UCameraComponent' class UCameraComponent* FPSCameraComponent; ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSCharacter.cpp:27:30: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'USceneComponent *' with an lvalue of type 'class UCameraComponent ' FPSMesh->SetupAttachment(FPSCameraComponent); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/SceneComponent.h:653:40: note: passing argument to parameter 'InParent' here void SetupAttachment(USceneComponent InParent, FName InSocketName = NAME_None); ^ In file included from /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.cpp:4: /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.h:27:5: error: unknown type name 'USphereComponent' USphereComponent* CollisionComponent; ^ In file included from /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.gen.cpp:8: /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.h:27:5: error: unknown type name 'USphereComponent' USphereComponent* CollisionComponent; ^ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.h:31:5: error: unknown type name 'UProjectileMovementComponent'; did you mean 'UPawnMovementComponent'? UProjectileMovementComponent* ProjectileMovementComponent; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ UPawnMovementComponent /Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/Pawn.h:23:7: note: 'UPawnMovementComponent' declared here class UPawnMovementComponent; ^ In file included from /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.cpp:4: /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.h:11:5: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'UObject *' with an rvalue of type 'AFPSProjectile *' GENERATED_BODY() ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:616:29: note: expanded from macro 'GENERATED_BODY'

define GENERATED_BODY(...) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(CURRENT_FILE_ID,_,LINE,_GENERATED_BODY);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:611:37: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE'

define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(A,B,C,D) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:610:43: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER'

define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D) A##B##C##D
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all) /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.generated.h:82:2: note: expanded from macro 'FPSProject_Source_FPSProject_FPSProjectile_h_11_GENERATED_BODY' FPSProject_Source_FPSProject_FPSProjectile_h_11_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS \ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.generated.h:56:58: note: expanded from macro 'FPSProject_Source_FPSProject_FPSProjectile_h_11_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS' DECLARE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR(NO_API, AFPSProjectile); \ ^ /Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:1588:11: note: expanded from macro '\ DEFINE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR_CALLER' return new (EC_InternalUseOnlyConstructor, (UObject*)GetTransientPackage(), NAME_None, RF_NeedLoad | RF_ClassDefaultObject | RF_TagGarbageTemp) TClass(Helper); \ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/apple/Documents/Unreal Projects/FPSProject/Source/FPSProject/FPSProjectile.h:31:5: error: unknown type name 'UProjectileMovementComponent'; did you mean 'UPawnMovementComponent'? UProjectileMovementComponent* ProjectileMovementComponent; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ UPawnMovementComponent /Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/Pawn.h:23:7: note: 'UPawnMovementComponent' declared here class UPawnMovementComponent; ^

Comment: Please be more specific than "it gives me multiple error codes". What exactly are the errors?

Comment: I will repost the question with the error codes

Comment: Edit this question instead!

Comment: Done. Added the errors

Comment: Update. So I have been making some progress in fixing the codes there is just one error I keep getting and it goes as follows.                                                                               
#error "FPSCharacter.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in FPSCharacter.h" 
I am confused about this error as #pragma once is in the code for FPSCharacter.h

Comment: Could you please include in your post "FPSProject.h"?  you have it in FPSProjectile.cpp and FPSCharacter.cpp.

Comment: I already fixed the error I just had to add a class to the UCameraComponent in FPSCharacter.h